# Mounting mess up - need advice

Tags: walls, kitchens, mounting, studs

I was asked to mount a bar to suspend cookware from in a kitchen. The plan was to use toggle bolts and mount it above another suspended cookware bar.

I began drilling my 5/8" hole through the drywall, and I hit the stud.  I switched to a 5/8" wood drill bit ( *paddle style* ), and drilled about 4 inches through the stud, when my worst fears were realized - there's no gap on the other end, just more drywall.

So now i have two 5/8" diameter, 4" ( *inch* ) deep holes where I want to mount this bar, and I'm not sure the best way to proceed.  Ideally sink some kind of anchor in there, probably meant for block or concrete, and mount the bar using the tension of the anchor?

Please advise, home improvement gumshoes.  I'm trying to look good for my girlfriend on this one.

Comment: Whats the bracket system that's meant to hold it in place, do you have to use those big toggle bolts and not a wall plug instead? Pehaps a picture of the bracket might help.

Comment: there's a type of nut with a wood thread on the outside and a machine thread on the inside. they are used in flat-pack furniture  "Knife threaded insert"  if you can find that with a 5/8" or 16mm  nominal outside  dimension that would probably solve your problem

Comment: an expanding anchor could spit the stud.

Comment: I've never seen a 5/8 foot paddle bit. Also wouldn't you write that as 7.5 inches?

Comment: FYI. If you have stud at the mounting location you do not need an anchor. You can use a wood screw or lag bolt to screw directly into the stud. **I agree with Jasen's answer, glue a dowel in the hole**.

Comment: Impress your girlfriend and Tell her you came here to  ASK FOR ADVISE. **Women like a man who is smart enough to admit mistakes and ASK FOR ADVISE ( and directions )** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the hole, glue in a 5/8 wooden rod/dowel  using white glue, panel adhesive, epoxy, or polyurethane wood glue. Then drill into the end of that and use some sort of long wood screw to attach the bracket.

Alternatively, get a threaded insert or connector nut that accepts the machine screw part of the toggle bolt and fix that into the oversize hole using wooden wedges and epoxy putty or builder's filler.

Comment: You may have to sand the dowel just a bit to get it fit the hole. Wood glue will be sufficient. It is ok if the dowel is recessed in the hole a little but you do not want it stick out proud of the stud.